# Error in -"mod" : invalid argument to unary operator

Tags: r, geolocation

I am using GeoLight package  in R and when I come to `twilightCalc` function as following

```
twilight<- twilightCalc (grw1$dt, grw1$light, LightThreshold= TRUE, ask= TRUE)
```

I got interactive chart and at the end I should have a data frame "twilight" but instead I got this message

```
Error in -"mod" : invalid argument to unary operator
```

Can any one help, what does this mean??

Comment: Try using `traceback` to see which sub-function threw the error.  We will have an easier time helping you if you post a small, reproducible dataset (`grw`) for us to work with.

Comment: here is a a part of my dataset

date                  light
05/07/2010 20:02 46
05/07/2010 20:04 40
05/07/2010 20:06 36
05/07/2010 20:08 40
05/07/2010 20:10 28
05/07/2010 20:12 24
05/07/2010 20:14 20
05/07/2010 20:16 16
05/07/2010 20:18 14
05/07/2010 20:20 12
05/07/2010 20:22 11
05/07/2010 20:24 11
05/07/2010 20:26 12
05/07/2010 20:28 12
05/07/2010 20:30 4
05/07/2010 20:32 5
05/07/2010 20:34 1
05/07/2010 20:36 0
05/07/2010 20:38 0

but first i have to change the time to "UTC"

grw1$dt<- as.POSIXlt(grw1$date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz='UTC')

and then run the function twilightCalc